# Java copy string containing LF to clipboard seems to add CR to it

Tags: java, clipboard

Given the small sample below to copy a string to the clipboard on a Windows 10 machine running Java 1.8:

```
String copyMe = "abc\ndef\nghi\n";
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection(copyMe), null);
```

Which looks like this:

[image: intellij]

The `\n` which is a line feed that has ascii code `0xA` at some point seems to be converted to a \r\n (where \r is the carriage return that has ascii code `0xD`).

Thus looking at the result when copied to Notepad++:

[image: notepad++]

If I use a tool like [Free Clipboard Viewer](https://freeclipboardviewer.com/) then I see similar:

[image: freeclipboardviewer]

I am not sure where the problem lies.

Can I just copy the string with `\n` to the clipboard without any intervention from up above?

**Update 1**

Debugging internals of Java...

`WClipboard` seems to hit this line 41 of decompiled .class file:

`byte[] var6 = WDataTransferer.getInstance().translateTransferable(var1, var5, var4);`

Where var6 contains:

[image: WClipboard]

Thus at this point it looks like the `\r\n` is in place.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is fault here.  You are copying text to the **Windows** clipboard.  Windows uses `CR` + `LF` as its line separator sequence.  To me, it is unsurprising that the text is acquiring Windows style line separators when it is copies to the clipboard.

Now, you ask where this is happening.

I think it is happening on the Java side, though my evidence is indirect.  Consider the following bug report against the Atom text editor.

-- https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/8365

Note that they complaining that when Atom copies text with Unix-style line terminators to the Windows clipboard, the line terminators are NOT converted.  That implies (to me) that the conversion is not happening on the Windows side.  (If it was, then there wouldn't be a problem for Atom.)  So if it is not happening on the Windows side, then for *your* example it must be happening on the Java side.

But the other thing that that bug report tells us is that most people think that conversion to Window line terminators is the *natural* and *desirable* behavior when copying *text* to the clipboard.

In the light of that, I think that it is your expectations that are incorrect, rather than the default behavior.

(I will see if I can track down where the conversion is happening in the OpenJDK source code ... and update this answer.)

Comment: OK thanks.  I just had a quick debug through and added some info to the question.  However if you copy a Notepad++ text to the clipboard which only has the line feed then that appears to be fine.

Comment: Could be `DataTransferer#translateTransferableString`.  `String var6 = (String)nativeEOLNs.get(var4); ... if (var10 == '\n') {
                        var8.append(var6);`